# Error: No operator << matches these operands?

Tags: c++, operators

I was practicing some c++ (trying to leave Java), and I stumbled on this annoying error saying:Error: No operater << matches these operands. I've searched this website for a clear answer and no luck, I did find that I'm not the only one.

This error is in my .cpp file, there are other errors, but I'm not paying any mind to them right now.

```
void NamedStorm::displayOutput(NamedStorm storm[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(storm); i++){
        cout << storm[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Something is up with the "<<" im not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are trying `cout` a class object you need to overload `<<`

```
std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const NamedStorm& namedStorm)
```

Comment: Wow, that actually did it. Is there anywhere I learn about overloading "<<"s?

Comment: C++ primer is a great book for all concepts

Answer (score 2):

You must overload the `<<` operator in order to redirect your object into a stream.

You can overload as a member function, but in this case you must use the syntax `object << stream` in order to use that overloaded function.

If you wish to use this syntax `stream << object` then you must overload the `<<` operator as a 'free' function, that is, not a member of your NamedStorm class.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class NamedStorm
{
public:
    NamedStorm(std::string name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out) const
    {
        // note the stream << object syntax here
        return out << name;
    }

private:     
    std::string name;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const NamedStorm& ns)
{
   // note the (backwards feeling) object << stream syntax here
   return ns << out;
}

int main(void)
{
    NamedStorm ns("storm Alpha");

    // redirect the object to the stream using expected/natural syntax
    std::cout << ns << std::endl;

    // you can also redirect using the << method of NamedStorm directly
    ns << std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

The function which is called from the free redirection overload must be a public method of NamedStorm (in this case we are calling the `operator<<` method of the NamedStorm class), OR the redirection overload must be a `friend` of the NamedStorm class in order to access private fields.

Comment: uh huh...Yeah that kinda flew over my head.

Comment: Sorry :/ do you have any specific comments or questions about what I wrote? I'm happy to try and explain it so it makes sense :)