# ostream operator << for address and a pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I have the following classes implemented:

```
class NUMS {
   int* numbers;
   int size;
  public:
   ostream& operator << (ostream& out, NUMS const& nums) {
       for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) out << nums.numbers[i] << " \n";
       return out;
   } 
};

class A

class B : public A {
   NUMS* numbers;
   public:
     C& func() {
         C* c = new C();
         return *c;
     }
     ostream& operator << (ostream& out, B const& b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < b.numbers->get_size(); ++i) out << b.numbers[i];
        return out;
     }
};

class C : public B
```

In my `main`:

```
A* a = new B();
B& b = a->func();
cout << a;
cout << b;
```

The ostream operator doesn't work at `cout << b`. what is my problem?

Comment: Could you fix your definitions for class A and class C, please?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: class A has some pure virtual functions.. and class C has nothing (just to "copy" a class B) in order to do the second line in my main..

Comment: You want the pointer value?  `cout << &b;`.  On a side-node, you realise that `func` is leaking horribly, right?

Comment: yes, I got an error.. and I want that cout << b will work, not cout << &b; thanks!

Comment: @paddy, how should I define func? thank you!

Comment: If you want the function to return a pointer, then return a pointer, not a reference.

Comment: and this line will work? `B& b = a->func();`

Comment: and then the lines of the cout will work also? thank you!

Comment: `ostream& operator << ` takes one parameter if you make it member funtion. Or you should add friend in front to make it free funciton.

Comment: If you want to use the notation `cout << b` then you need a free function, not a method, to overload the operator. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16513148/588476

Comment: No, if `func` returns a `C*`, you'd normally write `B* b = a->func()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `operator <<` overload should be a global operator, and it should also be a `friend` of the class so it can have access to the class' private data members:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, NUMS const& nums)
{
    // ...
}
```

The same also goes for the `<<` overload in `B`.

You're mostly likely getting undefined behavior in `func`, but what I think you should do is remove all instances of pointers and `new` in your code, as they aren't needed. `new` is not used to create instances of classes, it actually allocates dynamic memory.

Your `func` method could return a stack-allocated instance of `A` instead:

```
C func()
{
   return C();
}
```

It should also return it by-*value* because returning by reference would cause a dangling reference immediately after the ending brace because the temporary object will have already been destroyed.

I think you're confused about what the following lines are doing:

```
cout << a;
cout << b;
```

The first one prints out the value of the *pointer* (i.e an address). It isn't calling any operator overload in this case. The compiler won't even get to print `b` because of the incorrect lines before it.

If you want `cout << b` to work, you must change the way you initialize it. From this:

```
B& b = a->func();
```

to simply

```
B b;
```

Printing out `b` from there should work. I'm not sure about what you're trying to do with `a->func()` or the `C` class, I don't think there's even any reason for it in your program.